# How to set an event for all pages in ASP.NET dynamicaly

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to fire one event for all ASP.NET pages.
I don't want to duplicate this in all pages. So is there a way to do so for all pages ?
It might be available in web.config ?

My goal is to translate all pages before send to client.
So keep in mind I can't use events before Rendering because the controls texts are unknown.
Also we can't use events after Unload because we have no permission to write stream after this.

Any idea ?

Comment: How is this question related to `asp-classic`? What have you tried? What event do you want to share across all pages? How do you _translate_ your pages?

Comment: I haven't tried anything and the event I want to share is TranslatePage(Control C).. All I want is to get fired for each page.

Comment: Why you not place this TranslatePage function on Master Page.?

Comment: @Name: That's not an event but a method. Which event from `Page` do you want to handle at one place?

Comment: @ Harshit Tailor : I have tried it but doesn't get fired. which event of the Master Page I should use ?

Comment: @Tim Schmelter.. I prefer to use Render event of the pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want hardcoded translation of the controls to be fired after rendering them? I think that you should check [using resources for localization in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw69ke6f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). And if you prefer allowing changes in translations, consider using solution suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14686239/is-there-any-net-standard-for-dealing-with-localization-yet-allowing-the-users).

**EDIT:**

If you really need to fire method for each page, try binding to one of events handled by MasterPage. [Here is an ordered list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dct97kc3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) of events fired by content pages and Master page.

If you won't be able to achieve what you want to do with Master page, you can try creating new page that inherits from `System.Web.UI.Page`, defind the behaviour in this page, and then make all other pages to inherit from this page and not from `System.Web.UI.Page` directly.

Comment: i don't want to use resources since that won't help me.

Comment: @Namemustbeatleast3char Why do you need to translate controls using separate function? I don't understand why not use resources.

Comment: Because actually this is not a translation. it was just an example

Comment: @Namemustbeatleast3char As you can see that example is a bit confusing - you should write what exactly you want to do to allow us to post answer that really fits your needs.

Check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks your updated answer is the only way to achieve what I want.